# When to use t-SQL over the Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Could someone tell me if there are any times when it is more advantageous to use t-SQL over the Entity Framework? I'm aware of the N+1 issue, but is there any other gotchas I should be aware of? For instance, do Linq-to-EF queries cache as well as stored procedures? Are there instances where the SQL generated by EF is less than optimal?

Thanks!

Comment: EF is great for general-purpose operations, on single objects or smallish collections of objects. But for bulk operations, like inserting 100'000 rows into a database *fast* - I would use T-SQL over EF every time. Also: if you need to do significant calculations/computations on large data sets, returning only a single value or a small number of values - do that on the server and just return the results - don't suck down millions of row to come up with a single value in the end.....

Comment: Re: your second point, wouldn't that be just as applicable for calling a stored procedure from code as it would be to query using EF? Or is there a nuance I'm missing?

Comment: No, absolutely - if you have a stored procedure handling the heavy lifting on the server - by all means, do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you need to do the work "inside" the DB server  and not go back and forth between your code and Server.

Also - when you use stored procedures, you can alter the code without recompiling/deploying, it might be easier on production environments.

IMHO it sometimes easier to code complex SQL statements in T-SQL rather than using LINQ....